# Text and Autoincremented number together in a field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table, where the fields are labeled with an auto-incremented number at the end, such as:

Comp1
Comp2
Comp3

Is that possible? then if yes, how?

Comment: Your question is a little broad and needs more details. How will you be inserting data in this table? Is this field a unique or primary key?

Comment: If the text is static like in your example you should strip the text before insertion, auto increment the column, and add it back in your output script. If not, split the data into 2 columns (one text and one auto increment ed),  and combine them in your script at execution.

Comment: no you can't , but why you want to prepend the text , you can do while quering or to your application level for display purpose.

Comment: Data will be inserted through forms in web app. This field is the primary key. When user post data, a new record with this primary key will be added @ nikhil

Answer (score 1):

I have a question for you first. Will the word "Comp" ever change?

If it will never change just create a column called id that's auto increment and prefix it as "Comp" in your code.

If the word "Comp" may change you have the option to split into two column. One id and another prefix. You will be querying with the id and prefix in your where clause.

```
Select * from yourtable where id=2232 and prefix ="Comp";
```

Another option is what you exactly desire, create a column of type binary(16) and use the hex() and unhex() functions to store and retrieve the id. However you will still need to maintain a separate column for auto incrementing ID. If you don't want to do that then before you insert get the last inserted record and then increment it yourself then insert. But this may have the chance for collision. Be sure to index this field you plan to query it. Get a buy in from your DBAs as they won't be happy as your index will grow larger :)

Comment: Comp never changes, thnx for the answer :)